Fullstack архитектура с react-приложением и nginx
Строю архитектуру для сильно нагруженных сервисов и не совсем уверен в том, что должно делать приложение на React в связке с Nginx.
Например: Пользователь по URL стучится в Nginx. Nginx работая как прокси-сервер перенаправляет запрос на приложение React.
Приложение React каким-то образом надо развернуть как веб-сервер? (serve / nodejs express / next.js) И в случае, если потребуется обращение к данным в бд, уже методами nodejs обращаться далее к бекенду?
Nginx же тоже можно настроить как веб-сервер для раздачи статичных файлов. Но как тогда посылать запрос на бекэнд и обрабатывать ответ...
При этом, каждый кубик - это отдельный docker контейнер.
Вопрос: как нужно deploy react приложение в моем случае? Как отдельный webservis?


У вас в докере 3 nginx, 6 java-приложений и 2 БД?

Каждое приложение в своем docker контейнере. Если на схеме элементов более 1, значит их может быть множество.

Nginx отдает статику, т.е ui сборку react, ui стучится дальше к api, через тот же nginx, который по url проксирует запрос в нужный сервис.

И всё же, react как должен быть развернут?
Как отдельный вебсервер? С возможность отправлять/получать http?
Т.е. оборачивать его в nodejs express / nextjs / serve
